# Android - AndroidMediaUtils: Image_getJpegSize

Tags: android

I am implementing the below method, but Logcat warn : "AndroidMediaUtils: Image_getJpegSize: No JPEG header detected, defaulting to size=width=6000000"`

```
private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener =
        new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                // get image bytes
                ByteBuffer imageBuf = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                final byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageBuf.remaining()];
                imageBuf.get(imageBytes);
                image.close();

                onPictureTaken(imageBytes);
            }
        };
```

How can I resolve it? I'am very appreciate if you can help me. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what hardware you're trying to run this code on, but my own project involves a Raspberry Pi 3 and Android Things.

I have asked a couple of questions regarding this in the Google IoT community https://plus.google.com/communities/107507328426910012281 but didn't get any response on this particular question.

I have spent several hours trying to combat this, and have come to the conclusion that you can't really do anything about the warning if you're capturing images in JPEG format.

This means that you will be handling a 6MB byte array, likely unnecessarily. The largest resolution you can capture on a Raspberry Pi 3 with a camera v2 module and Android Things is 640x480, which really shouldn't create 6MB large arrays.

What I can do, however, is to post process this and output something that isn't 6MB in size, by creating a Bitmap from the raw buffer, which seem to be able to sort out the final result quite well. This is in no way optimised code, as I just now found a solution to my specific problem, and would like to share it with you:

```
Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
ByteBuffer imageBuf = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
final byte[] imageBytes = new byte[imageBuf.remaining()];
imageBuf.get(imageBytes);
final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.length);
int bytes = bmp.getByteCount();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "mypic.jpg");
try {
    // Write to SD Card
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    image.close();
}
```

A bug report has been created that can be followed/read here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62018053

Comment: Woww, Thank you very much. My case is the same to you. I run Android Things in Raspberry 3 to implement my IoT project which require using camera to capture photo. I found that image after getting buffer need to be compress to jpeg once again. This certainly is a bug.

Comment: I've added a link to a bug report on the Android Things bug tracker, that you could follow to see what they say. I don't know of anything more I can do at this point.

Comment: I'll keep track of your link. Thank you very much. By the way, may I know your current project with Android Things?

Comment: Sure, it's nothing fancy. Just a daily Twitter status posting of an avocado tree in the making. You can find links to my projects at http://shellstrom.tel
By the way, if you find the answer satisfactory, could I ask that you accept it as well?

Comment: yah, I accepted it. However, unfortunately, my point and my level is not enough to vote for you. Many sorry!

Comment: Thanks for still wanting to assist, Hay. That's really strange. If you accepted it, there should be a green check mark on it, and there isn't. I understand that you cannot upvote, but setting the answer as accepted should be possible. Could you double check it?

Comment: Actually, I am just stack overflow-er beginer. Many sorry! I've already accepted for you. By the way, I've also request making friend with you in Facebook, have you seen that?

Comment: No problem. Just keep using StackOverflow and you'll get the hang of it. You got yourself some extra reputation points added by accepting the answer as well, which is good for the future. And keep track of the bug report, they updated it today. Good luck with Android Things!

Comment: Had this problem on Android (API 28/29), too. The workaround described worked here, too. Thank alot!